# Msgbox item within a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I don't quiet understand what is going wrong here. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I can simply print the cells item when I hard code in the cells location, However, when I pass the cells location in, it doesn't show the value within the cell. Why is this?

```
Sub Button6_Click()
    Dim col As Long
    Dim row As Long
    col = 2
    row = 2
    MsgBox Sheets("MYSheet").Cells(2, 2).Value
    MsgBox Sheets("MYSheet").Cells(row & "," & col).Value
End Sub
```

Msgbox one passes back a value of "Working" which is located within Cell 2,2.

Msgbox two passes back a value of "" which doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Cells does not take a string but two longs.  change `row & "," & col` to `row, col`

Comment: @ScottCraner you should post it as an answer, since it's a legitimate answer, and for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells does not take a string but two longs.

Change `row & "," & col` to `row, col`

```
Sub Button6_Click()
    Dim col As Long
    Dim row As Long
    col = 2
    row = 2
    MsgBox Sheets("MYSheet").Cells(2, 2).Value
    MsgBox Sheets("MYSheet").Cells(row, col).Value
End Sub
```